# Read Whole Text Linux Bash File

Tags: linux, bash, file-io, text-files

How can one load a whole text file into a single variable?

I want to do that in order to glue several text files into one.

Basically I am trying to emulate the preprocessing phase for a language that does not support preprocessing (SMT2)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Do you actually need the contents in variables or are you just trying to con`cat`enate multiple files into a single file?

Comment: My particular need was to concatenate.

Answer (score 3):

There is another approach in bash without using cat:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(<file.txt)
echo "$var"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple! just use `cat`:

```
variable=`cat somefile`
```

Or, more properly:

```
variable=$(cat somefile)
```

They both do the same thing and will achieve the desired result (the latter is more readable, and you can nest it like:)

```
variable=$(cat $(find ./ -name "someFile"))
```

In your case, it seems that you want to do:

```
variable=$(cat file1 file2 file3)
```

Comment: In so far as they are both forms of Command Substitution they do the same thing, although they're not equal.  From [3.5.4 Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) in the Bash Reference Manual:  "When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by ‘$’, ‘‘’, or ‘\’. The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution. When using the $(command) form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially."